# How we can change OS for Google App Engine flexible? Or can we do this at all?

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, debian, glibc, apt-get

The one I always ends with is:

```
Linux gae-default-1-c9cf 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64
```

but I need some another version with glibc 2.14.

The current's one glibc is 2.13:

```
ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+deb7u11) 2.13
```

And I can't upgrade glibc on this OS, because after `apt-get update` and `apt-get install libc6` I getting this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

And I can't modify `sources.list` because of:

```
-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
```

So all I need is another OS for my GAE flexible app. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can build a custom dockerfile either by referring one which fits your requirements or specifying it from scratch: [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build)